# overcome ajax page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I am building a application with many form submissions and using ajax to send data to server (node js). I have a table to be updated on a button click , and on click I need to load a spinner and call the ajax post request to server. On server  it takes some time to update and send back result to ajax success. So on ajax success I hide the load spinner and update the data to table. Everything works fine problem is meanwhile when ajax req is called and server side is executing query the user may reloads the page, when page reloads ajax call is cleared so i cannot hide the load spin and update success data to html. What is the possible solution to avoid this

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: 'POST',
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   data: formdata,
   success: function (data) {
     if (data.status == 'Success') {
       toastr.success(data.msg);
       // code to hide load spin
      // update result data to html
    }
 })
```

Comment: Why can't you hide the loading spinner? Please provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: after the ajax call the user refresh the page that will clear the ajax call before ajax success gets executed

Answer (score 0):

You can do three things listed below in the order of complexity:

1. Put warnings on the page for users not to press reload or back buttons. This approach is often adopted on payment gateways when credit card details are verified server side. You can show a modal dialog box with the warning and spinner graphic.

2. Use session variables on server side to detect interruptions to ajax calls. For example you can have a variable called ajax_status (values none, incomplete and complete). You can set this variable at the start and successful completion of an ajax call. On page load, if you find the variable set to incomplete, show an error message, saying ‘something went wrong, have you pressed the reload button?’

3. Extend the 2nd approach to save ajax call parameters and reinitiate the request on page reload (show a warning saying data refresh was interrupted and reinforce message re not reloading).

Comment: I dont want to reninitiate  ajax since I already made the request I want only the ajax success part to be executed even after page refresh

Comment: If a user press the reload button before ajax is complete, how will you display the data after page refresh?

Comment: that is my question actually, since I made the ajax call, the process will be done in server side but I could not display that in front end

Comment: I have already answered this in my original response. You save the state of ajax request on the server using Session variables. Then on reload, you check the Session variables in js, and if required reload and display the data. 

In option 2 - you let user reload the data. 

In option 3, the javascript reinitiate the ajax and reload data.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a page refresh(re-load) while all of your code is being executed by changing your html form action -

```
<form id="myForm" action="javascript:void(0)"></form>
```

This will also maintain HTML standards without fancy code to manipulate element functions.

Comment: I suggest using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: How will this prevent users from reloading the page by pushing the browser reload button?